# show this inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}a_{i+1}}{1-(a_{i+1}-a_{i})^2}\le \dfrac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality, summation

let $n\ge 2$  integer, and $a_{i}\ge 0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$ such $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=1$,show that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_{i}a_{i+1}}{1-(a_{i+1}-a_{i})^2}\le\dfrac{1}{2}$$
where $a_{n+1}=a_{1}$.

I want to put the denominator $1-(a_{i+1}-a_{i})^2\ge A$ then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_{i}a_{i+1}}{1-(a_{i+1}-a_{i})^2}\le\dfrac{1}{A}\sum_{i}^{n}a_{i}a_{i+1}\le
A\dfrac{1}{4A}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{4A}$$
if we find a best $A\ge \dfrac{1}{2}?$

where use well know inequality
$$(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdot+x_{n})^2\ge 4(x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}x_{3}+\cdots+x_{n}x_{1})$$

[Maximize $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_nx_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252103/maximize-x-1x-2x-2x-3-cdotsx-nx-1)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_ia_{i+1}}{1-(a_i-a_{i+1})^2}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i+a_{i+1}}{4}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
We used the following inequality.

> let $a$ and $b$ be non-negative numbers such that $1-(a-b)^2\neq0$ and $a+b\leq1$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{ab}{1-(a-b)^2}\leq\frac{a+b}{4}.$$

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$4ab\leq a+b-(a+b)(a-b)^2$$ or
$$4ab+(a+b)(a-b)^2\leq a+b,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$4ab+(a-b)^2\leq a+b$$ or
$$(a+b)^2\leq a+b$$ or
$$a+b\leq1$$ and we are done!

Comment: There is an error Michael...

Comment: @The.old.boy Where? I don't see...

Comment: How to you find the $\dfrac{ab}{1-(a-b)^2}\le\dfrac{a+b}{4}?$

Comment: @function sug I don't understand your question. Say me, do you agree that it's true? If you don't agree, see please my proof and ask please  your questions.

Comment: You have $a_{i-1}$ instead of $a_{i+1}$ no ?

Comment: It was typo, dear @The.old.boy :) I fixed. Thank you!