# Proof by induction for an optimisation problem

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Could you give your mathematical  and logical analysis or approach about my induction proof ?

**Origin of the problem**
This problem is Problem 2166 from [Mathematics Magazine](https://maa.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0025570X.2023.2177036).

The only thing I don't prove here, is the result for $n=3$. The goal of this discussion is not about this case because it is much standart than the general case. I just recommand to you to read resources or to prove this case.

I hope posting here my original proof will not violate the spirit of the problem, neither the explicit rules of MAA.

I thank respectfuly MAA and the author for having submited this problem.

**Problem**
Minimising
$\frac{x_1+x_2}{1+x_1x_2}+\frac{x_2+x_3}{1+x_2x_3}+\dots+\frac{x_n+x_1}{1+x_nx_1}$
non-negative $x_i$ satisfying $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=1$

**Claim**
Let $c$ a not null positive real number lower than $1$.

$\forall n \ge 3$, the minimum of $\frac{x_1+x_2}{1+x_1x_2}+\frac{x_2+x_3}{1+x_2x_3}+\dots+\frac{x_n+x_1}{1+x_nx_1}$, $x_i$ none-negative numbers satisfying $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=c$ is $c + \frac{4 c}{4+c^2}$ for $X=X0(c)=(\frac{c}{2},\frac{c}{2},\ 0,\ \dots,\ 0)$.

**Proof**
By induction on the number $n$ of variables $x_i$.

*Base case*
$k=3$ is a known solved problem for which we know that the solution is for $X=(\frac{c}{2}, \frac{c}{2},\ 0) \forall c \in\ ]0;\ 1]$ that gives the minimum $c + \frac{4c}{4+c^2}$ ($\frac{9}{5}$ when $c=1$).

*Induction step*
Let $k \gt 3$ and $(c, C) \in\ ]0;\ 1]^2$, two real numbers.

Let $X=(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$, and $U=(u_1, u_2, \dots, u_{k+1})$ two finite set of real positive variables such as $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=c$ and $u_1+u_2+\dots+u_k+u_{k+1}=C$.

Let $g(X)=\frac{x_1+x_2}{1+x_1x_2}+\frac{x_2+x_3}{1+x_2x_3}+\dots+\frac{x_{k}+x_1}{1+x_{k}x_1}$

Let $f(U)=\frac{u_1+x_2}{1+u_1u_2}+\frac{u_2+u_3}{1+u_2u_3}+\dots+\frac{u_{k}+u_{k+1}}{1+u_{k}u_{k+1}}+\frac{u_{k+1}+u_1}{1+u_{k+1}u_1}$

We suppose that the induction hypothesis is right for $n=k$, in other words, that the minimum of $g$ is for $X=X0(c)$.

Let show in this step that it implies that it is right for $n=k+1$. In other words that the minimum of $f$ is for $U0(C)=(\frac{C}{2},\ \frac{C}{2},\ 0,\ \dots,\ 0,\ u_{k+1}=0)$.

Given that $f(U)=g(u_1,\ u_2,\ \dots,\ u_k) + \left(\frac{u_k + u_{k+1}}{1+u_k u_{k+1}} + \frac{u_{k+1} + u_1}{1+u_{k+1} u_1} - \frac{u_k + u_1}{1 + u_k u_1}\right)$
$= g(u_1,\ u_2,\ \dots,\ u_k) + h(u_k, u_{k+1}, u_1)$ with
$h(u_k, u_{k+1}, u_1)=\frac{u_k + u_{k+1}}{1+u_k u_{k+1}} + \frac{u_{k+1} + u_1}{1+u_{k+1} u_1} - \frac{u_k + u_1}{1 + u_k u_1}$
$h(u_k, u_{n+1}, u_1)$ is obviously minimum for $u_{k+1}=0$, and is equal to $0$ as soon as $(u_k=0 \vee u_1=0)\ \big(h(0, 0, u_1)=u_1-\frac{u_1+0}{1+0}=u_1-u_1=0 \big)$.

So we can conclude that $f(U) \ge g(u_1,\ u_2,\ \dots,\ u_k)$.

Obviously a solution with $u_{k+1} = C$ is not possible because it would mean $u_1=u_2=\dots=u_k=0$ and $f(0,\ 0,\ \dots, C)= 2C$ which we can assert, is not the minimum.

Then $u_{k+1} \ne C$, and $(C-u_{k+1}) \gt 0$.

In other words, we have to minimise $g(U)$, under the constraint $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k} u_i=C-u_{k+1} \in\ ]0;\ 1]$.

Thus, we can use the induction hypothesis for $n=k$ and assert that $g(U)$ is minimised for $U=U0(C)=(\frac{C-u_{k+1}}{2},\ \frac{C-u_{k+1}}{2},\ 0, \dots,\ 0, u_{k+1})$

Let $m=u_{k+1}$

The calculus of $g(U0(C))$ gives :

$\dfrac{C-m}{1+\frac{(C-m)^2}{4}} +\dfrac{C-m}{2} + \frac{c+m}{2+m(C-m)}$

A study of variation of the function $d$ on $[0;\ 1]$ :

$d(x)=\dfrac{C-x}{1+\frac{(C-x)^2}{4}} +\dfrac{C-x}{2} + \frac{c+x}{2+x(C-x)}$

shows that the minimum is for $x=0$.

So $g(U)$ is minimum for $m=0=u_{k+1}$ and is equal to : $C + \frac{4 C}{4+C^2}$.

In conclusion, $U0(C)=U0=(u_1, u_2, 0,\dots, u_k=0, 0)=(\frac{C}{2}, \frac{C}{2}, 0, \dots,\ 0, u_{n+1}=0)$ minimises $f(U)$ since it minimises $g(u_1,\ u_2,\ \dots,\ u_k)$ and $h(u_k, u_{k+1}, u_1)$.

So eventually we showed that
$\forall n \ge 3, \forall\ c \in\ ]0;\ 1] \frac{x_1+x_2}{1+x_1x_2}+\frac{x_2+x_3}{1+x_2x_3}+\dots+\frac{x_n+x_1}{1+x_nx_1}$ $x_i$ none-negative real numbers satisfying $x_1+x_2+\dots + x_n=c$ is minimised for $X=X0(c)=(\frac{c}{2},\frac{c}{2},\ 0,\ \dots,\ 0)$ and is equal to $g(X0(c))=c+\frac{4 c}{4 + c^2}$.

QED.

Our claim is now proved and we'll use it to solve the initial problem.

By taking $c=1$ in our claim, we proved that the minimum is $g(U0(1))=1 + \frac{4}{4+1}=\frac{9}{5}$.

Comment: Maybe related to the question [Minimizing $\frac{x_1+x_2}{1+x_1x_2}+\frac{x_2+x_3}{1+x_2x_3}+\dots+\frac{x_n+x_1}{1+x_nx_1}$ for non-negative $x_i$ satisfying $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4680488/89922).

Comment: @peterwhy I think the OP had answered the question, however many users pointed out some faults....

Comment: It's the same problem and the same solution found, but my proof is very simple on the contrary. Please note that this discussion is about the proof of the claim written in my post.