# Finding Maximum Value using AM-GM Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let us have a set of natural numbers $S=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ where $n≥4$, $n$ is even, such that all $(x_i\in S)≥0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1$.
Find the maximum value of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i*x_{i+1})$.

---

My approach to the problem:
We have $x_1,x_2,...,x_n≥0$. Since $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=1$, it implies that any $x_i>1$ is not possible. Further, even if one $x_i=1$, then all other have to be zero.
Therefore $0≤x_1,x_2,...,x_n≤1$. Using **AM$≥$GM**, we have $\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}≥x_1x_2$ with equality$\iff x_1=x_2$. Now to find $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i*x_{i+1})$, we add respective inequalities.$$\frac{x_1^2+2(x_2^2+x_3^2+...+x_{n-1}^2)+x_n}{2}≥x_1x_2+x_2x_3+...+x_{n-1}x_n$$ with equality holding if and only if $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$. It gives $RHS_{max}=\frac{n-1}{n^2}$.
Kindly correct me if there is a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: It seems you really didn't mean natural numbers were defining $S$, but non-negative real ones.  Further, $x_1=x_2=\frac12, x_{n>2}=0$ does a much better job of maximising what you want.

Comment: ... or any other pattern with for some $j: 1<j<n$ where $x_j=\dfrac12$ and $x_{j-1}+x_{j+1}=\dfrac12$ and the rest $0$, also giving $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i\,x_{i+1} =\dfrac14$.

Comment: Related, but not quite the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252103/maximize-x-1x-2x-2x-3-cdotsx-nx-1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to use AM-GM to find this maximum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_ix_{i+1} \leqslant(x_1+x_3+...)(x_2+x_4+...)\leqslant \frac{(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+\cdots)^2}4=\frac14$$
Equality is possible when any two adjacent $x_i, x_{i+1}$ are $\frac12$ and the rest $0$, so this gives the maximum.

Comment: +1 though there are some other cases where the sum is $\frac14$ too.

Comment: @Henry Yes, saw your comment, those cases also give the maximum.  Seems your linked post is almost identical, it doesn't seem to matter if $x_nx_1$ term is not there (but for more equality cases), or that $n$ is even/odd.

Comment: The only substantial difference with the other question seems to be when $n<4$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the maximum value of the sum is $\frac{n-1}{n^2}$.

But the inequality which you have used while solving the problem is not AM-GM inequality. It is RMS-GM inequality ($RMS \ge AM \ge GM \ge HM \ for\ positive\ real\ numbers$).

Comment: The RMS-inequality is better known as QM-AM (quadratic mean). Also AM-GM was used in the question for the squares of the $x_i$-s.

Comment: Can you prove what you say - that the maximum is $(n-1)/n^2$?